# .NET Decompiled sources fail to build

Tags: .net, decompiling, decompiler

I am new to c#/.net/obfuscators.

I have a working application. 1 .exe and multiple .dll Each of the dlls reference other dlls. Each those files are in the same folder.

At first I started using Dotpeek to have a look at the code and I even exported to project. After trying to read code full of letters and failing, I discovered that the code was actually obfuscated. After using google for many many many hours... I found there were other decompilers aswell deobfuscators.

I found de4dot and used it to deobfuscate every file. When I run them they worked fine, exactly the same as the original files.

Now, when I used Dotpeek I could see the source clearly with readable names. After exporting into a Visual studio project. I tried to build it, but there lots of errors, the most part was the presence of unicode-escaped characters "\uxxxx" in symbols. So I spent some time doing a python script to convert all those characters into the respective unicode characters. Even then there were other errors like nonnuable-type used as nunable-type, access inconsistencies, generic constraints, etc.

I started fixing them by hand but there were so many I started looking for other decompilers. After trying all the other available decompilers, I found that ILSpy was the only one that didnt crash when decompiling to project

Again, When I tried to build it, there errors, but this time there were less of them, and again I started fixing one by one.

Some of the fixes were straight forward but others did not make sense. For example. There was a compile time error saying that a declaraction cannot be an expression. When I look at said expression, it was basically a sum and multiplication of a struct type variables, which has no effect on the run flow.

This got me to read the assembly code (which is actualy IL for this case) and in that particular instruction it did exactly that, sum and multiply, no use of the value. Why is there an instruction like that in IL code? How was it compiled in the first place? Is it some voodo-magic from the obfuscator?

Also there were these compiler generator code comment warning on the source code, should I keep that code?

What makes all the these compile-time errors on the c# generator sources? Is it decompilers faults? Or is it the deobfuscator faults?

What should I do? Keep fixing the remaining errors? Are there any other tools for there jobs? I cannot find any deobfuscator besides de4dot. I couldnt found other decompilers, other than dotpeek and ILSpy, that worked.

Comment: _"Is it decompilers faults? Or is it the deobfuscator faults?"_ - Both. A deobfuscator / decompiler can only "guess" what C# code was used to generate given IL. I'm afraid there's little to say other than "keep trying to make it work".

Comment: @CodeCaster I see, that means guessing is not the best solution. But there must be alternatives to guessing. One could make a decompiler that would only stop decompiling when the aproximation error would be low. So that at each try at decompiling, it would compile the result and compare it to the original binary, and adapt its decompiling algorithm. That would certainly be challenging.